# How to get rid of the outline view when developing a new perspective for an eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing a new perspective for my eclipse plugin. For that I added a perspective extension and now I want to just display my view without the default outline view. I did it like that:

```
public class JazzPerspectiveFactory implements IPerspectiveFactory {


    private static final String VIEW_ID = "jazzperspective.views.MainView";

    @Override
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        IFolderLayout left = layout.createFolder("left", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, layout.getEditorArea());
        left.addView(VIEW_ID);

    }

}
```

But nevertheless, the outline view is still displayed. How can I get rid off it? My perspective should look like this (view 1 and view 2 are my views and editor is the default editor).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting your workspace. The perspective layout is cached in `[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml`

Comment: or reset your open perspective to pick up your perspective factory changes.